# Каким образом в си шарпе можно вывести изображение из файла в консоль?

Tags: c#

Делаю игру змейку по видео урокам, консольная змейка, есть идея вместо символов вставить картинку..Допустим, чтобы стенки по периметру состояли из повторяющейся картинки, которая лежит в корневой папке, и тело змейки также, вместо символов состояло бы из картинок.

Comment: Тогда вам надо посмотреть видео уроки по wpf.

Comment: Либо консольная программа с символами шрифта, либо оконное приложение с полноценным UI и картинками, но не оба вместе.

Answer (score 2):

Да не делают так, как вы хотите.

Обычно делают приложение с GUI интерфейсом (winforms, wpf) и нормальной графикой, либо выводят ASCII символы.

Например, вы можете нарисовать на экране вполне приличный прямоугольник из обычных символов: см. [Box-drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

А змейку рисовать звёздочками. Да, это не очень красиво и по стилю напоминает змейку на Nokia 3310.

Но если очень хочется в учебно-тренировочных целях доставить себе много приключений - то вот вам ссылка в качестве отправной точки для изучения:

[Display a Image in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33538527/5752652)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответы!
Еще один вопрос... при выводе символов на экран, т е по сути тела змейки, перед головной точкой стоит мигающее подчеркивание, как  то можно убрать?

Comment: @ДмитрийИванов: Вы хотите превртатить консоль в не-консоль. Просто не делайте так, освойте UI-программирование. Оно и в будущем пригодится.